# Methods to ignore missing word features on test data

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification, missing-data

I'm working on a text classification problem, and I have problems with missing values on some features.

I'm calculating class probabilities of words from labeled training data.

For example;

Let word foo belongs to class A for 100 times and belongs to class B for 200 times. In this case, i find class probability vector as [0.33,0.67] , and give it along with the word itself to classifier.

Problem is that, in the test set, there are some words that have not  been seen in training data, so they have no probability vectors.

What could i do for this problem?

I ve tried giving average class probability vector of all words for missing values, but it did not improve accuracy.

Is there a way to make classifier ignore some features during evaluation just for specific instances which does not have a value for giving feature?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

There is many way to achieve that

- Create and train classifiers for all sub-set of feature you have. You can train your classifier on sub-set with the same data as tre training of the main classifier.

For each sample juste look at the feature it have and use the classifier that fit him the better. Don't try to do some boosting with thoses classifiers.

- Just create a special class for samples that can't be classified. Or you have experimented result too poor with so little feature.

Sometimes humans too can't succefully classify samples. In many case samples that can't be classified should just be ignore. The problem is not in the classifier but in the input or can be explain by the context.

- As nlp point of view, many word have a meaning/usage that is very similare in many application. So you can use stemming/lemmatization to create class of words.

You can also use syntaxic corrections, synonyms, translations (does the word come from another part of the world ?).

- If this problem as enouph importance for you then you will end with a combination of the 3 previous points.